# How to generate the name of model in the layout when access to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When access to a specific view in wanting to generate a model name for this view in layout.

I need a passing model name from view to layout "dynamic way to all views"

Comment: you mean @mymodel= ...? or in controller?

Comment: I have many of view each view has model, I want a dynamic way to get the name of the model for this view

Comment: in @layout .... model for view in layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you can try this:

```
@model.GetType().Name  // in the view
```

And if you want get model name in the controller then:

```
var model = new MyCustomViewModel();
var modelName = model.GetType().Name;
```

Edit:

As you explained in comment if you want access some view data in layout you can try this:

```
var currentControllerName = Url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var currentActionName = Url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Or you can share data between layout and view with **ViewBag**.

Set ViewBag in view:

```
@ViewBag.Title= @model.GetType().Name;
```

Then you can read it in layout:

```
@ViewBag.Title// in layout
```

Comment: in layout?!,    I want a model name in the layout

Comment: are you passing any model to the layout?

Comment: no, I didn't ... I need a passing model name from view to layout "dynamic way to all views"